# MVC: Still can navigate to the pages after log out if clicking on `Back` button in the browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, caching

After logout, I still can navigate to the pages if clicking on `Back` button in the browser.

In my case, if I type in the `URL` and click enter, I log out from the application and cannot  open the page if typing it directly, since, my controller has `Authorize` attribute set. So, unless I authenticated, I cannot directly go to the page.

However, when using the browser's `Back` button, I'm still allowed to go back to the previous page.

I thought that it has something to do with Session or Cache, so, when hitting log out link, I'm executed the following code:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
if (authCookie != null)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon();
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);  // HTTP 1.1.
    Response.Cache.AppendCacheExtension("no-store, must-revalidate");
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
    Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
    Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.
}
return View();
```

But it did not solve the problem.

How can I fix that?

Comment: You can delete cookies all you want, that doesn't matter if the browser takes the page out of its cache and doesn't even make a request to the server ... And with the headers you are setting in the code shown, you are influencing caching behavior for your logout URL only. If you wanted to influence caching of other resources/pages, then you need to set according headers for those, the first time they are requested.

Comment: So, basically, on each Index methods in each controller, I would have to write the same code?

Comment: No, ideally that would be handled at a different level, like the default configuration for the response class you are using.

Comment: My problem is that I can go back to the pages with `Back` button after I singed out or navigated to Login page using `Back` button

Comment: I understand perfectly well what your problem is. And I told you what you have to do to fix it. (In broad strokes, of course - detail research is your part. And while doing that you will f.e. discover, that you might not need to disable caching completely, but that you can instruct the browser to check again with the server before displaying a cached page.)

Comment: I have added the code in `Application_BeginRequest` method of `Global.asax` file and in each ciontrollers' Index method. However, I'm still having the same problem

Comment: Well then do a little debugging, and check what headers your browser actually receives via dev tools ...

Comment: Does it have to do anything with using `@Ajax.ActionLink`?